# Display opening hours table

Tags: php, arrays

```
"hours" => 
        [
            'Sun' => ['00:00' => '02:00', '18:00' => '23:59'],
            'Mon' => ['00:00' => '02:00'],
            'Tue' => NULL,
            'Wed' => NULL,
            'Thu' => ['18:00' => '23:59'],
            'Fri' => ['00:00' => '02:00', '18:00' => '23:59'],
            'Sat' => ['00:00' => '02:00', '18:00' => '23:59'],
        ],
```

I have this array with the opening hours of a restaurant. The restaurant is open from 6pm until 02am.
What is the best way to display a PHP table similar to Google's?
[Google table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9RCb.jpg)

When I try to display using the array, I am unable to modify the output to consider "02am" as part of the previous day.

**I cannot modify the structure of the array, it is already used elsewhere.**

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a simpler way to do this since the times all seem to be same which means you can hard code some values, I will assume this can change.

This code takes a start time and the number of hours the location is open. It then can generate the closing time based on that.

```
$hours = [
    'Sun' => [
        'open' => '18:00',
        'closed' => '+8 hours'
    ],
    'Mon' => null,
    'Tue' => null,
    'Wed' => null,
    'Thu' => [
        'open' => '18:00',
        'closed' => '+8 hours'
    ],
    'Fri' => [
        'open' => '18:00',
        'closed' => '+8 hours'
    ],
    'Sat' => [
        'open' => '18:00',
        'closed' => '+8 hours'
    ],
];

foreach ($hours as $day => $time) {
    if ($time === null) {
        printf('%s Closed%s', $day, PHP_EOL);
        continue;
    }
    $open = new DateTimeImmutable($time['open']);
    $closed = $open->modify($time['closed']);
    printf('%s %s %s %s', $day, $open->format('H:i'), $closed->format('H:i'), PHP_EOL);
}
```

Outputs

```
Sun 18:00 02:00 
Mon Closed
Tue Closed
Wed Closed
Thu 18:00 02:00 
Fri 18:00 02:00 
Sat 18:00 02:00
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gd5s7)

Comment: Thank you @John Code, but that way it wouldn't do for me either. A clinic that closes at lunchtime, could not have two hours in a day for example.